# Does tar create point-in-time snapshots?

Tags: ubuntu, unix, tar, posix, gnu

I know that `tar` can be used to create a backup.

However I wonder if the operation creates **point-in-time** backups or not.

Basically I wonder if it grants consistency if the directory and files are being added / modified / deleted in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

No. You have to do that on your own and make `tar` read from the snapshot.